# sum of every other digit and doubling the rest

Tags: python

I'm working on a card number check code, for now I created a function that asks for the card number and checks if it is 8 digits or not (it has to be 8) and then calls another function that will do the math and check if the card is valid. For this function:

1. Starting from the rightmost digit, form the sum of every other digit. For example, if the card number is 1234 5678, then you form the sum 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 = 20
2. Double each of the digits that were not included in the preview step and then add all digits of the resulting numbers. For example, the digits that were not included are 7 5 3 1, we double the, 14 10 6 2, and then we sum each digit, 1 + 4 + 1 + 0 + 6 + 2 = 14
3. Add the sums of the two steps, 20 + 14 = 34, if the last digit is 0 then the card is valid, otherwise it is not valid (which is our case)

My problem is that I don't know how to iterate and get the sum of every other digit or double the other number which were not included in step 2. My thought was to use a while loop but then what?

EDIT: since some answers used lists... we didn't study lists yet, so I should not use it, we are only allowed to use sample stuff, loops, functions, etc.. even sum(map()) we didn't study

That is my code for now (its not much but just thought put it anyway)

```
def getCard():
    CardInput = int(input("Enter your 8 digit credit card number: "))
    if len(CardInput) == 8:
        CardCheck(CardInput)
    else:
        print("Invalid Input: Should be exactly 8 digits!")
        getCard()
def CardCheck(CardNumber):
    Position = 0
    Sum = 0
    DoubleSum = 0
    FinalSum = 0
    while CardNumber >= 0:
        Position += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the *ugly* way of doing is, you can write a for loop and use indexing for access specific elements

```
for i in range(len(CardInput)):
    # it will iterate from 0 to 7
    print(CardInput[i]) # here you get ith element
    if i % 2 == 1:
        print("I am other!") # you can sum your things here into another variable
```

Or with `while`:

```
while position < len(CardInput):
    print(CardInput[position])
    position += 1
```

It assumes CardInput is `str`, so I recommend to not convert it earlier.

However pythonic way would be

```
sum(map(int, CardInput[1::2])))
```

`CardInput[1::2]` returns list of every second element starting from second (0 is first).

`map` converts every element to in.

`sum` sums elements.

Comment: I forget to say this in the OP but we are not allowed to use lists

Comment: Technically we didn't used a list - we used slices, strings and Iterables, there is no list at all.

Comment: *Technically*, according to the requirements it should be `test[-1::-2]`, though it's functionally the same.

Comment: I mean - `str` is something like list of chars (it's not, but for now you can think of it that way), so if you use `str` you kinda use `list` and `indexing`.

Comment: To sum up, solution with `for` doesn't use list and I think it's something that your professor meant. The `for` loop can be changed to `while` too, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to iterate over the digits, it's actually easier IMO if you leave it as a string, rather than converting the input to an `int`; that way you can just iterate over the digits and convert them to `int` individuall to do math on them.

Given an 8-digit long string `card`, it might look like this, broken into steps:

```
even_sum = sum(int(n) for n in card[1::2])
double_odds = (2 * int(n) for n in card[0::2])
double_odd_sum = sum(int(c) for do in double_odds for c in str(do))
```

All together with some logic to loop while the input is invalid:

```
def get_card() -> str:
    """Returns a valid card number, or raises ValueError."""
    card = input("Enter your 8 digit credit card number: ")
    if len(card) != 8 or not card.isdecimal():
        raise ValueError("Invalid input: Should be exactly 8 digits!")
    card_check(card)
    return card

def card_check(card: str) -> None:
    """Raises ValueError if card checksum fails, otherwise returns None."""
    even_sum = sum(int(n) for n in card[1::2])
    double_odds = (2 * int(n) for n in card[::2])
    double_odd_sum = sum(int(c) for do in double_odds for c in str(do))
    if (even_sum + double_odd_sum) % 10:
        raise ValueError("Card checksum failed!")

while True:
    try:
        print(f"{get_card()} is a valid card number!")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: I like the idea of keeping it as a string, but yea we didn't learn lists so we should not use it

Comment: What a sophisticated program, f-strings, docstrings, exceptions handling, I am impressed,  but for sure you missed a logger :p

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt = "Enter the eight-digit number: "

while True:
    number = input(prompt)
    if len(number) == 8 and number.isdigit():
        break
    prompt = "Oops, try again: "

first_digits = number[1::2] # If the user entered '12345678', this will be the substring '2468'
first_sum = sum(map(int, first_digits)) # Take each digit (character), map it to a single-digit integer, and take the sum of all single-digit integers

second_digits = number[0::2] # If the user entered '12345678', this will be the substring '1357'
doubled_ints = [int(char) * 2 for char in second_digits] # Take each digit (character), turn it into an integer, double it, and put it in a list.
second_sum = sum(map(int, "".join(map(str, doubled_ints)))) # Merge all integers in 'doubled_ints' into a single string, take each character, map it to a single digit integer, and take the sum of all integers.

total_sum = first_sum + second_sum

total_sum_last_digit = str(total_sum)[-1]

is_valid_card = (total_sum_last_digit == '0')

if is_valid_card:
    print("Your card is valid (total sum: {})".format(total_sum))
else:
    print("Your card is NOT valid (total sum: {})".format(total_sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getCard():
   CardInput = input("Enter your 8 digit credit card number: ")
   if len(CardInput) == 8:
      CardCheck(CardInput)
   else:
      print("Invalid Input: Should be exactly 8 digits!")
      getCard()

def CardCheck(CardNumber):
   list_CardNumber = [x for x in "25424334"]
   Sum = sum(int(x) for x in list_CardNumber[1:8:-2])
   DoubleSum = 2*sum(int(x) for x in list_CardNumber[0:8:-2])
   FinalSum = Sum + DoubleSum
   if str(FinalSum)[-1] == "0":
      print("Valid Input")
   else:
      print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: Just `list("25424334")` would be the same as `[x for x in "25424334"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# lets say 
CardNumber = '12345678'

# as mentioned by kosciej16
# get every other digit starting from the second one
# convert them to integers and sum
part1 = sum(map(int, CardNumber[1::2]))

# get every other digit starting from the first one
# convert them to integers and double them
# join all the digits into a string then sum all the digits
part2 = sum(map(int,''.join(list(map(lambda x: str(int(x)*2), CardNumber[0::2])))))

result = part1 + part2
print(result)
```

Output:

```
34
```

Edit:
Only with loops you can use:

```
# lets say 
CardNumber = '12345678'

total_sum = 0
for idx, digit in enumerate(CardNumber):
    if idx % 2 == 1:
        total_sum += int(digit)
    else:
        number = str(int(digit)*2)
        for d in number:
            total_sum += int(d)

print(total_sum)
```

output:

```
34
```

Comment: I am pretty sure his professor won't believe he wrote it alone :p

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you should check out `enumerate()`, it'll simplify things if you're just going to use loops by giving you easy access to both the index and value every loop.

```
step1 = 0
for i, x in enumerate(number):
    if i % 2:
        print('index: '+ str(i), 'value: '+  x)
        step1 += int(x)
print('step 1: ', step1)
```

Output:

```
index: 1 value: 2
index: 3 value: 4
index: 5 value: 6
index: 7 value: 8
step 1:  20
```